# How to get my 2 column divs to stack on top of each other at equal width and length at different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

One div contains a **video** and the other **text**. The divs are responsive but do not stack on top of each other at equal height at different screen sizes. Here's what I've done so far:

```
.page-wrapper2 {
   margin: 0px;
   border: 2px solid black;
  }

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
 }

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
 }

.blue-column {
  background-color: blue; // for testing purposes
  height: 100%;
}

.red-column {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .row {
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100%;
   }
 }


  <div class='page-wrapper2'>
    <div class='row'>
     <div class='column'>
       <div class='blue-column'>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YIOb5_WCsOY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class='column'>
     <div class='red-column'>
      <h2>Red Column</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <button>Watch today</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

See my current result and now sure how to make the video larger:

https://jsfiddle.net/EF__1000/wzabLqcr/2/

Comment: They do have the same width, just not the same height. But why would they? The red column doesnt need as much height as the blue column when it takes 100% of the width

Comment: How do I get it to stack on top of each other at equal height @PhobosFerro? You got any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a bit of javascript as follows. More on getComputedStyle [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
window.onresize = (event) => {
  const bluecolumn = document.querySelector('#blue-column');
  const elementComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(bluecolumn);
  const redcolumn=document.querySelector('#red-column');
  redcolumn.style.height = elementComputedStyle.height;
  redcolumn.style.width = elementComputedStyle.width;
};
```

```css
.page-wrapper2 {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  // margin: 5px;
}

.blue-column {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

.red-column {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='page-wrapper2'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='blue-column' id="blue-column">
        <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YIOb5_WCsOY" title="YouTube video player"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='red-column' id="red-column">
        <h2>Red Column</h2>
        <p>Text in Red Two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe missing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">` in the head section? This piece of code is usually needed to make web pages responsive.

Comment: I have that already @Alec. Do you have any other solutions I can look at?

Comment: that code has nothing to do with responsiveness. All the code does is equalize the pixels (the difference between hardware and software pixels on mobile high-resolution devices).

Answer (score -1):

Try to include this line in your HTML head tag. It will ease your content responsiveness.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is an in-deep explanation from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: that code has nothing to do with responsiveness. All the code does is equalize the pixels (the difference between hardware and software pixels on mobile high-resolution devices).

Comment: Nope. It has everything to do with responsiveness. Without that viewport meta tag, it would be quite difficult to size everything and make fit the user's device viewport since each device's initial zoom differs and Usually, the rendered page (web content) is bigger than the viewport. That line basically fits website content to a device's viewport(Mostly mobiles) thus making it responsive in some ways. Here is an in-depth article about the [Viewport_meta_tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: re-read and understand what I said. for high-resolution mobile devices, there is a difference between physical (hardware) pixels and CSS (software) pixels. The difference exists for a reason which is important for usability and user experience. A responsive web design is not limited to that and will work just fine without it. All this line does is make it easier to write the correct media queries as the developer doesn't need to think or test cross-devices on the cost of poor user experience. Experienced frontend developers will solve responsive design issues just fine without adding this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).