# How to display 2 column layout with video and the other with text with a call to action

Tags: html, css

How to display 2 column layout with video and the other with text call to action. Video and text div should stack on top of each other at different screen sizes at equal height.

Mine is stacking on top of each other but not at equal height. See the code below:

```css
.bt-wrapper2 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.blue-column {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.red-column {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .blue-colum {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='bt-wrapper2'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='blue-column'>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YIOb5_WCsOY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='red-column'>
        <h2>Red Column</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <button>Watch today</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73543503/how-to-get-my-2-column-divs-to-stack-on-top-of-each-other-at-equal-width-and-len/73544584#73544584 ???

Comment: "equal height" - which of the two elements defines the height - or do neither of them define the height and something else does. Perhaps you require the video to take 100% viewport width and its aspect ratio to be used to define the height? Please be more specific.

Comment: Neither of them define the height. I want them equally stacked on top of each other at smaller viewports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get my 2 column divs to stack on top of each other at equal width and length at different screen sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73543503/how-to-get-my-2-column-divs-to-stack-on-top-of-each-other-at-equal-width-and-len)